# C# - Verify mocked (MoQ) property's method was called with part of string as a parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm using MoQ and C# to mock a public property and I want to know if one of the mock's methods was called with any strings starting with a particular set of characters.

So for example, while I know this works:

```
mockLogger.Verify(x => x.Information($"Entering {methodName}"), Times.Once);
```

I'm trying, with the below attempt, to see if `mockLogger`'s `Information()` method was called with a parameter starting with `$"Exception in {methodName} - Error Message: {ex.Message} - StackTrace:"`

```
mockLogger.Verify(x => x.Information($"Exception in {methodName}: " +
                                         $"Error Message: {exceptionMessage} - " +
                                         $"StackTrace: ........"), Times.Once);
```

Is this not possible? Or is there some sort of workaround?

EDIT:

I've even tried

```
    mockLogger.Verify(x => x.Information($"Exception in {methodName}: " +
                                         $"Error Message: {exceptionMessage} - " +
                                         $"StackTrace: " + It.IsAny<string>()), 
                                         Times.Once);
```

but it doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also just use `It.Is<string>()` which can perform a comparison.

```
string searchString = $"Exception in {methodName}: " +
                      $"Error Message: {exceptionMessage} - " +
                      $"StackTrace: ";
mockLogger.Verify(x => x.Information(It.Is<string>(s => s.StartsWith(searchString))), Times.Once);
```

This is probably a lot clearer than using `It.IsRegex()` as I suggested previously.

Comment: Brilliant! It needed another closing bracket after `searchString` like so: `s.StartsWith(searchString)))`, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @AshwinNair Thanks. Closing brackets in a verify always throws me for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to check for an exact match in the verify, you can look for a portion of the string, e.g.:

```
mockLogger.Verify(x => x.Information.IndexOf($"Exception in {methodName}:") >= 0 && x.Information.IndexOf($"Error Message: {exceptionMessage} - ") >= 0 && x.Information.IndexOf($"StackTrace: ") >= 0), Times.Once);
```

Comment: I've got a method called `Information()` in my `Logger` class but `x => x.Information.IndexOf` isn't recognized because it's a method not a string. I want to see if the parameter passed to the information method starts with a particular string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex to do this. Strings can be compared with the `It.IsRegex()` method which takes regex as a parameter.

An example would be

```
string regexString = "" //Substitute for actual regex to search what you want
mockLogger.Verify(x => x.Information(It.IsRegex(regexString)), Times.Once);
```

The following code sample from Moq's [quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) shows it being used in a setup but it works in Verify too:

```
// matching regex
mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsRegex("[a-d]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))).Returns("foo");
```

Comment: This looks promising. How would I use it in my case though?

Comment: I'm going for your answer below, but using `mockLogger.Verify(x => x.Error(It.IsRegex($"^{searchString}")), Times.Once);` based on your suggestion works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility could be to use [Callback](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks) method.
`Callback` method can receive the argument which was used to call the mocked method and so it is possible to do what ever custom verification you need. Example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void VerifyWithCallback()
{
    // Arrange
    bool startsWith = false;
    const string methodName = "methodName";
    Mock<ILogger> mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger>();
    SomeClassWithLogger cut = new SomeClassWithLogger { Logger = mockLogger.Object };
    mockLogger.Setup(l => l.Information(It.IsAny<string>())).Callback<string>(s =>
    {
        startsWith = s.StartsWith("Entering starts with test");
    });

    // Act
    cut.Logger.Information($"Entering starts with test {methodName}");

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(startsWith);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the moq documentation uses the VerifySet()  method when verifying Properties.  Have a look here:  https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: Thanks but how do i use `VerifySet` to overcome this issue though? I've used `Verify` to verify properties and methods that have been called with specific parameters but am unable to check for partial parameters as mentioned in my question.